# Convert unstructured data(text) into structured format using java

Tags: solr, web-crawler, search-engine, nutch, information-retrieval

I've done a lot of research on this and read few papers, checked all SO Q&A's but I'm still not clear.

```
        I'm trying to setup a small search engine. I am crawling data using nutch and 
        have integrated it with solr for front end and indexing.

        After crawl, I have unstructured data i.e content of entire page I crawled and 
        I need to structure this data into sets.
```

For example : I crawled a page which contains information about any product and I have raw text which has product description, size, dimension etc.

My goal: extract keywords I want say : dimensions --> store in DB column
Extract information related to dimensions --> store in same row(another column)

So, I have keyword and description in one table and I fetch as per query and output to user.

I'm not sure how to go about stucturing/fetching the information i need and I wish to do this using java, if possible. I read few articles, but I cant follow. Any help/guidance will be appreciated.

Please let me know, if you need more information. Appreciate your time and help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use nlp tools like GATE (https://gate.ac.uk/), Apache OpenNLP (https://opennlp.apache.org/), Minorthird (http://sourceforge.net/projects/minorthird/), etc.

You can write a jape grammar in GATE which creates annotations based on the words present in the text. For example you can annotate `dimension, measurements, proportions` etc as `dimension` and then look up for numbers in next sentence.

You can look into other nlp tools here: https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-best-Java-open-source-NLP-toolkits

Comment: Thanks. I'll check out the links. :)

Comment: I've searched for it but I'm not able to leverage the GATE API easily. Can anyone help by providing any links for examples ?

Comment: @SaurabhBhoomkar https://gate.ac.uk/wiki/code-repository/src/sheffield/examples/StandAloneAnnie.java

Answer (score 0):

Give a try to CogComp-NLP: http://deagol.cs.illinois.edu:8080/

It is available in Java, with Python api.